# Approximation of a differentiable function.

Tags: real-analysis

If $D\overset{f}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{C}$ is differentiable in $x_0$  $(D\subseteq\mathbb{R})$, the closer one gets to $x_0$ the smaller the difference between the linear function $l_{x_{0}}(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ gets. The Approximation is defined as:

$$\begin{align}
r_{x_{0}}(x) &:=f(x)-l_{x_{0}}(x)\\
&=f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0) \\
&=\left(\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f'(x_0)\right)(x-x_0)
\end{align}$$

How does one conclude that the left factor on the very Right side converges to $0$.

And how does one conclude by that that

$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{r_{x_{0}}(x)}{x-x_0}=0$

Comment: the limit of the left factor is zero by definition of derivative at $x_0$

Comment: You divide by $(x-x_0)$ both sides and use the fact that that left factor converges to zero